# factorial of non-integer value in java

Tags: java, factorial

5! = 5*4*3*2*1.

I have no problem with this. But I noticed with my program that if I type in say 3.5! it would return a defined  number.

How do you calculate them?

I have something like this in my program

```
 public class fact {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     double factorial=1;
     System.out.println("Type a number");
     double number= sc.nextDouble(); /*I am using scanner*/
     while (number !=0 ){
       factorial = factorial * number;
       number--;
     }
     System.out.println(factorial);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem? Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: refer this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454053/how-do-we-calculate-factorials-for-numbers-with-decimal-places

Comment: The factorial function is only defined for integers. Why do you want to accept 3.5 as input?

Comment: There is no such thing as the factorial of a non-integer value. There are extensions to the concept of "factorial", see Wikipedia: [Extension of factorial to non-integer values of argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Extension_of_factorial_to_non-integer_values_of_argument)

Comment: If you type `3.5`, your loop will never ends, maybe you should change it to `while (number >= 0)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a mathematics question rather than a programming question.

Comment: A function that computes that for non-integer numbers would be something like the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) as an extension to the factorial.

Answer (score 5):

Factorial in its normal definition is defined only for positive integers. If you want to calculate factorials for any real numbers, have a look at *Gamma functions*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: this is pretty much the correct answer! Gamma function  will allow to calculate the factorial of a double...

Answer (score 2):

Thing is: *factorial* is pretty simple for **whole, positive** numbers.

The concept can **also** be applied for floating point numbers, but the math behind that could be considered [*advanced*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Extension_of_factorial_to_non-integer_values_of_argument).

So: step back; and understand the **math** behind the concept; before implementing the concept!

In other words; you have to decide whether you intend to change your program to work with *int* numbers (validated to be > 0 ); or if you intend to allow floating point numbers. If the later is your goal; then your simple implementation won't do any more.

Beyond that: you want to study the concept of **floating point numbers** in the first place. It is a **misconception** to assume that a loop like

```
double number = ...
while (number !=0 ) {
  ..
  number--;
}
```

would always stop when using floating point numbers instead of int/long! To the contrary ...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the defined value even for 3.5!, because your code will calculate it as following:

```
1*3.5*2.5*1.5*0.5
```

But actually it is wrong value for 3.5!. The correct value is: `11.6317283966`. Your method is only valid for integer inputs. See this for more information about decimal factorials:
[this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396889/how-to-find-the-factorial-of-a-fraction)

Comment: Actually, the code in the OP won't stop there, because it checks for `number !=0`, which is still true below zero.